# Spring tutorial on Session Management

Tags: spring-mvc, spring

I want to learn how session management is being done in Spring web MVC.
Do you know any free tutorial on how is it being done?

I am thinking of similar sample applicatin such as BookStore or Shopping cart applications that I have done using basic servlets and JSP.

Kindly advise me how is it done and make it done the proper way in Spring Framework.

Thanks to all.

Comment: There are a dozen different ways to do it, Spring does not mandate any given approach. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Apparently there are four ways to do session management in Spring, one of which is directly interacting with the `HttpSession` object. Would someone mind pointing out the other ways?

Answer (score 3):

Use this filters to your purpose. Just extend the below mentioned HiddenHttpMethodFilter and write your own filter.

This class will be called for each request as pattern is given as /* . In this class redirect it to your logout controller.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at Spring Security: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/